# Unable to get values from placeholders in BeanPostProcessor

Tags: java, spring

I am using Spring with a legacy Tomcat application (not Spring Boot) that comes with Spring Boot BOM 2.4.0, the question is similar to [Spring Expression Language not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461703/spring-expression-language-not-working) but I have a specific case.

If I have a dependent class with `@Value("${spring.kafka.maximumRequestSize:15728640}")` and the following

```
@Configuration
@Order
public class KafkaTracingDecorator implements  ApplicationContextAware {
    private KafkaTracing kafkaTracing;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {

        kafkaTracing = applicationContext.getBean(KafkaTracing.class);
    }
}
```

It works.  The following also works, but I don't do anything on the post processor

```
@Configuration
@Order
public class KafkaTracingDecorator implements BeanPostProcessor, ApplicationContextAware {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(final Object bean, final String beanName) throws BeansException {

        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {

//        kafkaTracing = applicationContext.getBean(KafkaTracing.class);
    }
}
```

But when I try to implement the `BeanPostProcessor` to [implement the decorator pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54841554/how-to-implement-decorator-pattern-in-spring-boot/66272977#66272977) like this

```
@Configuration
@Order
public class KafkaTracingDecorator implements BeanPostProcessor, ApplicationContextAware {

    private KafkaTracing kafkaTracing;

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(final Object bean, final String beanName) throws BeansException {

        if (bean instanceof KafkaProducer) {
            return kafkaTracing.producer((KafkaProducer) bean);
        } else if (bean instanceof KafkaConsumer) {
            return kafkaTracing.consumer((KafkaConsumer) bean);
        } else {
            return bean;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {

        kafkaTracing = applicationContext.getBean(KafkaTracing.class);
    }
}
```

I get `Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${spring.kafka.maximumRequestSize:15728640}"` when the WebApplicationContext is being created.

This also happens even if I don't use the value so it's not going into the method

```
@Configuration
@Order
public class KafkaTracingDecorator implements BeanPostProcessor, ApplicationContextAware {

    private KafkaTracing kafkaTracing;

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(final Object bean, final String beanName) throws BeansException {

        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {

        kafkaTracing = applicationContext.getBean(KafkaTracing.class);
    }
}
```

Here's a very simplified example that also fails the same way:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaTracingDecorator implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.maximumRequestSize:15728640}")
    private int maxRequestSize;

}
```

(Note this works as expected on Spring Boot, so it's likely something to do with the non-boot usage of Spring)

A partial stack trace that leads to the error does not list any custom code:

```
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4689)
```

MVCE added: https://github.com/trajano/spring-beanpostproc-mvce linked to GitHub issue in case it is a bug https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26571 rather than a usage issue.

Comment: At which point the exception is happening ?

Comment: Start up when it is building the WebApplicationContext.  Updated the Q to include that fact

Comment: Can you share your codebase so that I can start and try to solve the issue ?

Comment: Can't do that, its not an open source project, I am trying to create an MVCE that shows it, but it's working in the MVCE itself.

Comment: Let me try on my own to reproduce this.

Comment: Thx I am basically adapting the Spring Boot starter to be a Tomcat + WAR deployment hopefully the problem will manifest.

Comment: It's working in my case in spring boot.

Comment: Working with tomcat as well. Tested on local as well.

Comment: I noted that it already works on Spring Boot.  I did add the MVCE that proves the failure now.  On a Dockerized tomcat.

Comment: what is MVCE ? By the way, I did some changes then it worked on tomcat with spring boot starters.

Comment: Can I share my answer ?

Comment: Minimum Valid Complete Example, feel free to share your answer.  Maybe it can shed light to what needs to change on my MVCE.

Comment: @AnishB. do you have an answer?

Comment: Yes I have. I will provide

Comment: Got the solution for your MVCE. Now it's working on my system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the `Decorator` class by registering the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean to resolve your issue.

According to [Spring Docs on PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) :

> **PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer** is a child class of **PlaceholderConfigurerSupport**. This child class helps in resolving `${...}` placeholders against local properties and/or system properties and environment variables.

Therefore, configuring this bean will load the **application.properties** from the classpath and it will be able to resolve `${..}` used in `@Value` annotation to get the actual value set.

Updated **Decorator** Class :

```
@Configuration
public class Decorator implements BeanPostProcessor {
    
    @Value("${spring.kafka.maximumRequestSize}")
    private int maxRequestSize;
    
    @Bean
    public static PlaceholderConfigurerSupport placeholderConfigurerSupport() {
        PlaceholderConfigurerSupport support = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        support.setLocations(new ClassPathResource("application.properties"));
        return support;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        System.out.println(maxRequestSize);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

**application.properties** :

```
spring.kafka.maximumRequestSize=15728640
```

Console logs of **Tomcat 8.5.57** running on **AdoptedOpenJDK 11.0.6** :

```
...
.....
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Feb 20, 2021 9:21:41 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
15728640
Feb 20, 2021 9:21:41 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext initialized in 518 ms
Feb 20, 2021 9:21:41 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Feb 20, 2021 9:21:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1419 ms
```

Comment: Yes the MVCE works with this change, going to try it on the bigger project.

Comment: I am thinking of asking this as another question, but which Resource can you use to let "environment variables" set the Properties..

Comment: Second part to this question, does the support bean need to be defined in this configuration or can it be outside?  I just tested, it can be outside, it may be a better answer to have it separate rather than embedded in Decorator

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano Yes, we can define support bean outside as well. But usually bean registration are done using `@Configuration` class. I never saw anywhere bean to be defined outside of the configuration classes. But still we can do that. There is no hard and fast rule to that.

Comment: also I noticed you use static, I tested on the MVCE and it does not look like it needs static

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano Yeah !! But without static, the data was not getting picked up . It was coming zero in my case. Is it picking up the right value from properties in your case?

Comment: it did, but just in case try in your MVCE support.setOrder(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE - 1);  Actually nix that,  if you make it non-static it gives a warning saying it's a bad idea :)

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano So, let the static keyword remain for that bean. Is it fine ?

Comment: It may still be a bug because in your answer you're creating a new mean but theoretically the bean should already exist since without the BeanPostProcessor the MVCE will work.  Until then your answer is the most valid one available.